# How do I make rolling text for a loading screen?

Tags: python, python-itertools

I want to make a loading screen that does this, but replaces the current line:

```py
LOADING
OADINGL
ADINGLO
DINGLOA
INGLOAD
...
```

**I want to be able to control the number of letters it prints at once**. What I tried:

```py
from itertools import cycle
from time import sleep

itr = cycle('LOADING')

for i in range(10):
    sleep(0.3)
    print('\r', ''.join(next(itr)))
```

But the output is:

```
 L
 O
 A
 D
 I
 N
 G
 L
 O
 A
```

Comment: `print` adds a new line by default after each call. You can change this behavior by using the `end` keyword in your call to `print`. `print("Hello", end="This is the end~")`

Comment: I know, that's the easy part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use the `end` keyword in `print` to avoid printing each message to a new line. I recommend the approach where you build the string to be displayed on each iteration and then display it. I don't like the `cycle` approach because you're unable to index into the `cycle` object very easily. Instead, we can use regular string indexing along with the modulus operator to ensure we don't go out of bounds and can still "loop" over the string over and over.

```py
import time

def scrolling_text(msg, n_chars):
    """
    Displays scrolling text of whatever 'msg' and ensures that only n_chars
    are shown at a time. If n_chars is greater than the length of msg, then
    the string displayed may "loop" around.

    Inputs:
        msg: str - The message to display
        n_chars: int - The number of characters to display at a time

    Outputs: Returns None, displays the scrolling text indefinitely.
    """
    len_msg = len(msg)
    counter = 0
    while True:
        displayed = ""
        for char in range(n_chars):
            displayed += msg[(counter+char)%len_msg]
        print(f"\r{displayed}", end="")
        time.sleep(0.05)
        counter = (counter + 1) % len_msg
    return

scrolling_text("LOADING", 25)
```

Each iteration of the `while True` loop will build the string to be displayed (inside the nested `for loop`) and then display it. At the end of the while loop, it would be enough to have `counter += 1` however for a long-running script, you might end up with `counter` being unnecessarily large. By letting `counter = (counter + 1)  % len_msg`, we can ensure `counter` never gets higher than the length of the message.

Answer (score 0):

Straightforwardly with Python *slicing*:

```
from time import sleep
from sys import stdout

s = 'LOADING'
for i in range(10):
    sleep(0.3)
    if i > len(s): i = i - len(s)
    stdout.write('\r' + ''.join(s[i:] + s[:i]))
```

Comment: I don't think it answers the question, OP wants one line of text at all times.

Comment: @CorentinPane, I don't understand your comment. What does mean "one line of text at all times" ?

Comment: "I want to make a loading screen that does this, but replaces the current line:". Each time you print something, it should overwrite the previous print.